# Correctness and Logic of algorithm: minimum steps to one

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic, correctness

Problem Statement:

On a positive integer, you can perform any one of the following 3 steps.

1. Subtract 1 from it. ( n = n - 1 )
2. If its divisible by 2, divide by 2. ( if n % 2 == 0 , then n = n / 2  )
3. If its divisible by 3, divide by 3. ( if n % 3 == 0 , then n = n / 3  )

Given a positive integer  n and you task is find the minimum number of steps that takes n to one .

My Recursive Solution (in C++) compares all the 3 cases when N is divisible by 3, while the general solution compares only 2, but still gives the correct solution.

```
int min_steps(int N){ 
        if(N==1) return 0;    
        else{
                if(N%3==0){
                       if(N%2==0) 
                          return (1+min(min_steps(N/3),min_steps(N/2),min_steps(N-1)));
                       else
                          return(1+min(min_steps(N/3),min_steps(N-1)));
                }
                else if(N%2==0){
                        return(1+min(min_steps(N/2),min_steps(N-1)));
                }
                else
                        return(1+min_steps(N-1));
        }
}
```

But the general solution is,

```
int min_steps(int N){ 
        if(N==1) return 0;    
        else{
                if(N%3==0){
                        return(1+min(min_steps(N/3),min_steps(N-1)));
                }
                else if(N%2==0){
                        return(1+min(min_steps(N/2),min_steps(N-1)));
                }
                else
                        return(1+min_steps(N-1));
        }
}
```

My question is, how come we don't compare all the 3 cases but still derive at the correct solution. I cannot follow the general solution's algorithm. Any help for letting me understand would be appreciated hugely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "general solution" is incorrect. Sometime's it's optimal to divide by 2 and then subtract 1, and the general solution code doesn't allow for that.

The "general solution" produces incorrect results for 642.

```
642 -> 214 -> 107 -> 106 -> 53 -> 52 -> 26 -> 13 -> 12 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
```

However, this is optimal, being one shorter:

```
642 -> 321 -> 320 -> 160 -> 80 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 9 -> 3 -> 1
```

You can see the general solution starts by dividing by 3, and the optimal solution starts by dividing by 2 and then subtracting 1... which is exactly the case that's been removed.

While it's not directly relevant to your question, here's the code I used to find the counter-example (albeit greatly tidied up since I wrote it). It uses the two algorithms you gave, but memoizes them for an exponential speed increase. It also uses a trick of returning two results from min_steps: not only the length of the shortest path, but also the first step in that path. This makes it extremely convenient to reconstruct the path without writing much extra code.

```
def memoize(f):
    """Simple memoization decorator"""
    def mf(n, div2, cache={}):
        if (n, div2) not in cache:
            cache[n, div2] = f(n, div2)
        return cache[(n, div2)]
    return mf

@memoize
def min_steps(n, div2):
    """Returns the number of steps and the next number in the solution.

    If div2 is false, the function doesn't consider solutions
    which involve dividing n by 2 if n is divisible by 3.
    """
    if n == 1:
        return 0, None
    best = min_steps(n - 1, div2)[0] + 1, n-1
    if n % 3 == 0:
        best = min(best, (min_steps(n // 3, div2)[0] + 1, n//3))
    if n % 2 == 0 and (div2 or n%3):
        best = min(best, (min_steps(n // 2, div2)[0] + 1, n//2))
    return best

def path(n, div2):
    """Generates an optimal path starting from n.

    The argument div2 has the same meaning as in min_steps.
    """
    while n:
        yield n
        _, n = min_steps(n, div2)

# Search for values of n for which the two methods of finding
# an optimal path give different results.
for i in xrange(1, 1000):
    ms1, _ = min_steps(i, True)
    ms2, _ = min_steps(i, False)
    if ms1 != ms2:
        print i, ms1, ms2
        print ' -> '.join(map(str, path(i, True)))
        print ' -> '.join(map(str, path(i, False)))
```

Here's the output, including run-times:

```
$ time python minsteps.py 
642 10 11
642 -> 321 -> 320 -> 160 -> 80 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 9 -> 3 -> 1
642 -> 214 -> 107 -> 106 -> 53 -> 52 -> 26 -> 13 -> 12 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1
643 11 12
643 -> 642 -> 321 -> 320 -> 160 -> 80 -> 40 -> 20 -> 10 -> 9 -> 3 -> 1
643 -> 642 -> 214 -> 107 -> 106 -> 53 -> 52 -> 26 -> 13 -> 12 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.009s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: Also, it reassured the correctness of my algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is divisible by `3` *and* divisible by `2`, then it does not matter if you divide by `3` first and then by `2` in the next step, or by `2` first and then by `3` in the next step.

Example: `18 = 3*3*2`

a) `18/3 = 6`, `6/3 = 2`, `2/2 = 1`, or

b) `18/2 = 9`, `9/2 = #!?#`, `9/3 = 3`, `3/3 = 1`, or ...

Comment: If you've got a multiple of 6, it's never optimal to divide by two and then subtract 1? That may be, but it's not obvious.